# What is the difference between asynchronous with waiting for result and synchronous?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, synchronous

Recently, I am learning multi-threading and asynchronous programing in java, while I found this confusing.

To be clear about my question: Are the codes below equivalent?

- If no, why? In my opinion, in the first snippet, the while loop will keep the original thread busy (meaning blocking?).
- If yes, how to use asynchronous properly?

```
//asynchronous programing

ExecutorService threadpool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Future<Long> futureTask = threadpool.submit(() -> factorial(number));

while (!futureTask.isDone()) {
    System.out.println("FutureTask is not finished yet..."); 
} 
long result = futureTask.get(); 

threadpool.shutdown();
```

```
//synchronous
long result = factorial(number)
```

Comment: Where did you find this example? I'd be very suspicious since it uses basically busy-waiting, instead of doing useful work on the main thread. Unless you count printing as useful work, but even then it's confusing.

Comment: There is no essential difference apart from the massive waste of resources in the asynchronous/wait case.

Comment: [link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-asynchronous-programming) I guess this example just want to show you how to use Future and ExecutorService. But It is not a good example apparently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When tasks are to be executed one after the other, using asynchronous methods does not really make sense: you lose the overhead of synchronization and still have to wait for the end of the processing. Furthermore, if you use an *active loop* to wait for the end:

```
while (!futureTask.isDone()) {   // active wait loop
    System.out.println("FutureTask is not finished yet..."); 
}
```

you add even more load to the system. At least you should use a `wait` method to put the current thread in a suspended mode until the other processing is finished.

But anyway, if tasks are to be executed one after the other, just call them synchronously one after the other:

```
factorial(number));
other processings...
```

It leads to cleaner and simpler to maintain code, with no performance loss.